# How to check whether a body is active in Corona?

Tags: coronasdk

I have a ball body and it is static first.
On touch event listener I am making it dynamic.
When I tried to check whether it is active for the first time with this function 
my_body.isBodyActive it is always returning true. why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer as I understand it is 'because it is active by default until you de-activate it'.

If you do not want it to be active then you you can deactivate it, see [this](http://developer.anscamobile.com/forum/2011/02/15/assertion-error-because-bodyactive) though: